# JS : display selections of a <select> multiple

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this example :

```
<form action="form_action.asp">
  <select multiple="multiple" name="example" size="10">
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="anything">Anything</option>
    <option value="else">Else</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And I want to display how many lines are selected (by CTRL + clic). I think I can do it with a bit of JS, but I have no idea how to write it.

Any idea ?

Comment: If it's a form submit, couldn't you just do it on the server side?

Comment: (That is not what I was looking for : the intention was just to display in real time the selection of <option>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First give your select an id

```
<select id="yourSelect" multiple="multiple" name="example" size="10">
```

then

```
var numSelected = 0;
var allOptions = document.getElementById("yourSelect");
for (var i = 0; i < allOptions.length; i++)
    if (allOptions[i].selected)
        numSelected++
```

For completeness, I'll mention that if you ever want to use jQuery, and I'm not saying you should for something this simple, but if you ever do, you can do this with

```
var numSelected = $("option:selected", "#yourSelect").length;
```

Comment: Why everybody offers JQuery for every javascript situations?

Comment: @moses - lots of people use jQuery.  It makes life more pleasant.  I answered OP's question using pure JavaScript, then I gave him a jQuery alternative if he was interested.

Comment: Well, plus-one for completeness.

Comment: @Adam - I will not argue about frameworks and their adv. or disad. But that is the same thing which offering a factorial algorithm with Boost in C++. After choise jQuery, he will never know about browser-compatibility. Whatever. You didn't do anything wrong. Just wonder.

Comment: @AdamRackis : just a little `document.getElementById("yourSelect").innerHTML = numSelected++;` and that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I googled and found [this article](http://www.digitalamit.com/blog/blog/23.phtml)

```
var selected = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < ob.options.length; i++) {
    if (ob.options[ i ].selected) {
        selected.push(ob.options[ i ].value);
    }
}
```

That will create an `Array` (`selected`) with the options.  You can alter it easily to get the number of items selected.

Answer (score 0):

Made an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/PM5544/9RJ5s/): 
but the core is:

```
function parseSelected() {
    var count = 0;

    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        if ( select[ i ].selected ) {
            count++
        }
    }
    output.innerHTML = count;
}
```